# How to make a titled box with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a titled box with css.
And my code is something like this.
I've ignored some attributes like width or height in my code.(Because I don't know why stackoverflow keeps telling me that I 've got too many codes here..)

```css
.sponsor_info {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.sponsor_info .headbar {
  border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
  width:200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #8BBE26;
}
.sponsor_info .headbar p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: arial;
    color:white;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsor_info">
  <div class="headbar">
    <p>Sponsor Info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can get something like below[image]

The question now is: I don't know why there is some space between the outer grey border and the inner green bar.

Comment: Because of this `margin-top:3px;`?

Comment: @Gosu Oh.. Hahahh thank you so much.. Sorry for this... :P

Comment: @Gosu But.. What if I want to make the text "Sponsor Info" in the center of the green bar vertically?

Comment: Does something like `text-align: center;` work in this case?

Comment: @Gosu well I think that works when I want to make the text in the center horizontally but not vertically right? .. @_@

Comment: How about this `vertical-align: middle;`? In the center of the green bar vertically right?

Comment: .sponsor_info .headbar p {
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.sponsor_info {
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 0px;
}
.sponsor_info .headbar {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: #8BBE26;
}
.sponsor_info .headbar p {
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsor_info">
  <div class="headbar">
    <p>Sponsor Info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much! Sorry for not expressing clearly.. But is it possible to make "Sponsor Info" on the left?

Comment: you just remove text-align

Comment: Mmm.. I want to make it in the middle vertically, but horizontally I also want it on the left.. :)

Comment: check snippet now:) text-align is meant for horizontal alignment, you just remove it and it defaults to left.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it now:)

Answer (score 0):

change it to:
    .sponsor_info .headbar p {
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    **margin-top: 0px;**
    }